# Delphi: Windows service calling DLL method: access violation error

Tags: delphi, service, delphi-10.1-berlin, delphi-11-alexandria

I have a Delphi **Berlin** Windows Service which will call a Delphi **11** DLL. This Delphi 11 DLL has REST API calls. I have used the following code to call the DLL method from my service:

```pascal
function RESTAPICall(sURL, sDomain, sID, sJson: String;
    var slLog: TStringList) : Boolean; stdcall; External Restcall.dll' name 'RESTAPICall' delayed;
```

Then I call this DLL method in the `OnTimer()` event in the Windows Service. But it throws an access violation error during runtime:

> Access violation at address 633381F4 in module 'Restcall.dll'. Read of address FFFFFFFC.

Also sometimes I get this AV error:

> Access violation at address 21285195 in module 'borlndmm.dll'. Write of address 6347C370.

Please note this error occurs only during Service call, it works fine if I call the DLL from EXE.

Comment: That function doesn't look like its arguments are safe to use across a DLL boundary. So it's not very surprising that you have problems.

Comment: You should read the [documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Sharing_Memory) and make sure you follow the rules.

Comment: More rules and advices: http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple words: you can't pass Strings or dynamic Arrays directly between application and DLL. You need to do one of the following:

1. Use the same memory manager for application and DLL by including it as first unit via `uses`.
2. Design you DLL functions to accept `PChar`, not `String`.

Note: I used [FastMM](https://github.com/pleriche/FastMM4) in a lot of projects but I don't know if it is working with Delphi Alexandria.

Comment: You missed to mention the ``TStringList`` parameter. This is also a no-go.

Comment: Please start to use formatting properly, especially [lists](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-lists). Rule of thumb: write it as if it would be correct in written documents, too (using dots, not hyphens). Also dare to link to mentioned software/products.

Comment: Also backticks are for `code`, not names in general. `String` is code, _Strings_ not.

Comment: Thanks All, My Bad.. Missed to use ShareMem in the Windows Service Code. Now it is good. It resolved

Comment: @SahayaJoni if you still use a ``TStringList`` parameter, you are doing it wrong and nothing is good! In the future it can happen that the two ``TStringList`` implementations (app and DLL) can differ from each other. That means they can have different memory representations and casting one to the other can lead to heavy problems, e.g. call another method than intended!

Comment: Yes, I am planning to change TStringList too.. Thanks